# SQL Query GROUP LIKE

Tags: sql

I have a table in which I capture each compute fault code.  I have both internal (20k fault codes) and external (60k fault codes)  I was to count the total number of fault codes based off

Here is what my data block looks like:

```
FaultCode   Count
20001       200
20002       100
60004       300
60034       80
```

The following code will give me the COUNT for each FaultCode.

```
SELECT FaultCode, COUNT(FaultCode) AS COUNT
FROM RmaSummary
WHERE ClosedTime IS NULL AND (FaultCode LIKE '60%' OR FaultCode LIKE '20%') 
GROUP BY FaultCode
```

However, I want to get the SUM for FaultCode LIKE '60%' OR FaultCodes LIKE '20%', example:

```
FaultCode     COUNT
60k            380
20K            300
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should tag the question with the specific database application you are using since it might influence the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression to group values:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN FaultCode LIKE '60%' THEN '60K'
       WHEN FaultCode LIKE '20%' THEN '20K'
    END AS FaultCode
    , COUNT(FaultCode) AS COUNT
FROM RmaSummary
WHERE ClosedTime IS NULL AND (FaultCode LIKE '60%' OR FaultCode LIKE '20%') 
GROUP BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN FaultCode LIKE '60%' THEN '60K'
       WHEN FaultCode LIKE '20%' THEN '20K'
    END
```

If you don't want to repeat the `case` expression you can move that part to a derived table or common table expression (if your database supports that).

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Why? The OP asks for a count.

Comment: `I want to get the SUM for FaultCode`... Actually, you are right. Sorry. I was confused by his first table in the question. That table is not the source raw data, it is a sample output of his current query. Your query is processing original raw data.

Comment: When I execute the above code, I get the following error  
    Column 'RmaSummary.FaultCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @EMIE Did you remove the FaultCode column from the select statement so that you only have the case expression? And what database are you using? I can run this code without issues.